# export SQL data to a csv file from ASP.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, csv

I have a view in the database, i would like to call that view and export the data to a Csv file. I have used the following link to come up with a solution however my view returns a few columns which has values with commas so while opening the csv i get the error the csv is unsafe, might by a sylk file etc. Once i open it there is no date in the CSV.

The link i used

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-data-from-SQL-Server-to-CSV-file-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

I am using VS 2017
SQL and 
VB.Net

Thanks in advance

Comment: The proper course of action is to wrap the field values in double quotes. You may choose to just wrap those that contain commas in quotes but, if you're going to use quotes at all, you should probably quote everything. Properly-written code for reading a CSV will handle quoted data, e.g. the `TextFieldParser` class.

Comment: Use a specialized library like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/. Saves you a lot of work and possible errors.

Answer (score -1):

That code is a bit dodgy actually, because it is explicitly replacing commas in data with semicolons and it is also adding an extra comma to the end of each line.  Here's concise way to generate CSV data from a `DataTable` with quoted field values:

```vb
Dim csv = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                      myDataTable.AsEnumerable().
                                  Select(Function(row) """" &
                                                       String.Join(""",""",
                                                                   row.ItemArray) &
                                                       """"))
```

If you're not au fait with LINQ, here's a more conventional way to do the same thing:

```vb
Dim csv As String

For rowIndex = 0 To myDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
    'Add a line break before all but the first line.
    If rowIndex > 0 Then
        csv &= Environment.NewLine
    End If

    Dim row = myDataTable.Rows(rowIndex)

    'Add a double-quote before the first field value.
    csv &= """"

    For columnIndex = 0 To myDataTable.Columns.Count - 1
        'Add a closing double-quote, a delimiting comma and an opening
        ' Double-quote before all but the first field value.
        If columnIndex > 0 Then
            csv &= ""","""
        End If

        csv &= row(columnIndex).ToString()
    Next

    'Add a double-quote after the last field value.
    csv &= """"
Next
```